# What if I use a false signature on a contract?

Tags: contract-law, breach-of-contract, signature

Suppose I sign a contract with a company to buy some amount of good in bulk but while signing I faked it, they wouldn't have a way to know if it's my actual signature and if I breach my contract I could just say I never signed it, they won't have any proof as the signature is not mine. How can you protect yourself from this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### In what way is the mark *you* made not *your* acceptance of the contract?

It doesn’t matter if it’s your name, or someone else’s name, or an X or the Bluetooth logo or a caricature of Donald Trump. You made it - it’s your signature.

Comment: Claiming that you didn’t sign it when you actually did could be fraud. Claiming that you signed “Mickey Mouse” means you admit you signed.